# How to store action.payload in redux-toolkit correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using redux toolkit to fetch users from an API and save the user's state in the store.

```
  userStore: {
    users: [],
    loading: true
  }
}
```

This shows up in redux-toolkit dev tools in firefox.

I was expecting it to be.

```
  userStore: {
    users: Array[..], //an array of 10 users
    loading: false
  }
}
```

I have configured the store in index.js

```
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        userStore: usersReducer,
    },
});

export default store;
```

userSlice.js

```
const initialState = {
    users: [],
    loading: false,
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'users',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        receivedUserList: (state, action) => {
            state.users = action.payload;
        },
        toggleLoadingUsers: (state) => {
            state.loading = !state.loading;
        },
    },
});

export const { receivedUserList, toggleLoadingUsers } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

User actions.js

```
export const fetchUsers = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch(toggleLoadingUsers());
        const response = await userAPI.get('/users');
        dispatch(receivedUserList(response.data));
        dispatch(toggleLoadingUsers());
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

I am using fetchusers in my App.js like this.

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { users, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.userStore);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('something');
        console.log(loading);
        console.log(users);
        dispatch(fetchUsers());
    }, []);
```

This is not updating the state correctly. How do I set the state after fetching users?
I have passed the store in ./store/index.js in src/index.js

```
import store from './store/index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind Redux's Toolkit is to remove boilerplate code for actions, types, and reducers and unified them into a single slice.

Let's refactor the user slice code as below.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk("users/fetchUsers", async (data) => {
  const response = await userAPI.get("/users");

  return response.data;
});

const initialState = {
  users: [],
  loading: false,
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    receivedUserList: (state, action) => {
      state.users = action.payload;
    },
    toggleLoadingUsers: (state) => {
      state.loading = !state.loading;
    },
  },

  extraReducers: {
    [fetchUsers.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [fetchUsers.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.users = [...state.users, ...action.payload];
    },
    [fetchUsers.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = action.error;
    },
  },
});

export const { receivedUserList, toggleLoadingUsers } = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Then import `fetchUsers` from  from `userSlice`

```js
//top-level import 
import {fetchUsers} from "../userSlice"


    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { users, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.userStore);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('something');
        console.log(loading);
        console.log(users);
        dispatch(fetchUsers());
    }, []);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use "state = action.payload" if I have only one action?

Answer (score 0):

```
**store code**
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        users: usersReducer,
    },
});

you have to add same name as you wrote in Slice

**while dispatchig data**

const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { users, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.users);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('something');
        console.log(loading);
        console.log(users);
        dispatch(fetchUsers());
    }, []);

**instead of usersStore keeep name same as in store**
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).